# How to implement Q-municate in my application.?

Tags: ios, swift, q-municate

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-ios (Sign in and sign up i've already done programmatically and works fine.) 
this is the project which i want to implement in my App , i've done only drag and drop the whole project in my app and Added bridging header file to get those objective C files , after that it gives me error like this:

> Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/Info.plist: “Info.plist” couldn’t be removed.

Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: Would you show readers your config files that import this library into your application?

Comment: https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-ios (Sign in and sign up i've already done programmatically and works fine.)
this is the project which i want to implement in my App , i've done only drag and drop the whole project in my app and Added bridging header file to get those objective C files , after that it gives me error like this.

Comment: ^ Updates should go **in the question itself** please. Use the edit link below the tags.